# (Windows 10) How can I output Google search results in a batch/powershell file?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, automation, output, google-search

I'm quite new to the whole automation process, and I've just recently started looking at tutorials trying to understand how to write .bat files (or Powershell, but from what I saw, it seems somewhat more complex for a beginner like me).

I'm trying, as the title says, to automate Google search, but also output the results. I know a few of the commands in .bat (for instance, cd to the browser directory and then

```
start launcher.exe "http://www.google.com/search?q=%%22how+to+code%%22"^&num=100
```

or

```
>results.txt (
**output here**
```

)

but I don't know how to *combine* these commands together, and in particular output a certain element of the result. So, what I'm looking for would be a way to output :

a) The website address (NOT the Google address, i.e. http://en.wikipedia.org/ instead of the long-ass link that's used as a redirect by Google)

b) The "preview" of at what point in the website content my phrase/keyword appears (see example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WasNT.jpg))

So my questions are :

1. How do I write a .bat/shell file to automatically search for a phrase, output the addresses/previews as written above, and move on to the next phrase, without opening a new tab (i.e., just staying on the same tab) - as a matter of fact, is there a way to do this without even opening the browser ?
2. If I *do* manage to write an automated program like this, would it be allowed by Google ? From what I remember, it's against ToS to use bots. Would writing "pause" between each search be enough ?
3. If it *isn't* allowed by Google, or can't be done, would there be any way to make searching for variation of a phrase more efficient (in my above example, it would be something like "how to code", but also "how to begin coding", "how can I learn to code", stuff like that) ?
4. I thought of making e-mail alerts using Google Alerts, but the problem with that is that : a) I believe there's a limit on the number of Alerts one can implement, and b) for phrases with tons of variations, it's still very tedious to input each variation in the Alert search box.

There ya go. I don't know if I'm being very clear, so don't hesitate to ask me for clarifications of my points, but I'd welcome the help anyone could provide (as a side-note, I forgot to add that I'm using Opera, if that makes any difference). Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is too broad to be answered here, StackOverflow is for programming questions (e.g here's some code I wrote, why isn't it doing x?). When you start to write a solution for this and get stuck, come back and we can help. As an aside, I strongly suggest skipping batch and learning PowerShell, it's infinitely more powerful and will make much of what you're trying to do easier.

Comment: Okay. Well then, where would I look for some information on how to go about doing this ?

Comment: It sounds like the first thing you need to do is learn how to write PowerShell. Specifically look at the Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet.

Comment: All right. Thank you. I'll go check that out, then.

Comment: This project/idea isn't what i would recommend for a beginner who doesn't know Powershell. I recommend you to first read a book about Powershell, start with some small stuff. When you know the basic ideas about Powershell, then start with " lets open google with my search phrase (just one)". When i get that done, lets see how i can get the content from that html file and filter out the part that i want.

Build up to what you want to accomplish, this way, the task will seem less daunting to achieve. 

Goodluck.

Comment: Batch script and shell scripts are **totally different** scripts. Batch scripts are for `MS-DOS`/`OS/2`/`Windows NT` systems. While shell scripts are for `UNIX-like` system. What script do you want?

Comment: By 'shell', I meant 'Powershell'. I thought that was a correct way of abbreviating the word, but perhaps I was wrong. Powershell **is** a Windows scripting environment, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes Powershell is a Widnows scripting environment. And `Powershell` should be abbreviated to `PS`(not formal, but like de facto) .